# Issues with load times when attempting to retrieve photos from Azure AD via Graph query

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I currently use the following code to pull information from Azure AD for a company directory:

```
List<QueryOption> options = new List<QueryOption>();
options.Add(new QueryOption("$filter", "accountEnabled%20eq%20true"));
options.Add(new QueryOption("$select", "displayName,companyName,profilePhoto,userPrincipalName"));

IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage users = await gsc.Users.Request(options).GetAsync();
userResult.AddRange(users);
while (users.NextPageRequest != null)
{
    users = await users.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
    userResult.AddRange(users);
}
```

It works relatively well, retrieving ~400 users' worth of data in roughly 5 seconds (I believe I can drop that time, but I'm not 100% clear on the best practices for dealing with async calls yet). The issue comes when I implement the following code to pull the user profile photos:

```
foreach(User u in userResult)
{
    Stream photo = await gsc.Users[u.UserPrincipalName].Photo.Content.Request().GetAsync();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        int read;
        while ((read = photo.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        imgMe.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
    }
}
```

This bit raises the page load time to over 30 seconds, and I'm having issues reducing that. So my questions in this specific situation are as follows:

1. Why does the original query (where I do specify profilePhoto in the select options) not actually pull the profile photo information?
2. What am I doing wrong here that creates such a drastic load time?

Comment: consider moving the code inside foreach into a method that returns Task and do a Task.WhenAll on all the tasks created for the users

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Why does the original query (where I do specify profilePhoto in the select options) not actually pull the profile photo information?

In Microsoft Graph API, it is designed as this. You can use [Get a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)  API to get basic user profile, at the same time, you need to use [Get photo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0) API to get photo.

So, in SDK, you will have the same experience.

> 2. What am I doing wrong here that creates such a drastic load time?

Actually, there is nothing wrong. But there is way to reduce the time cost. As @Matt.G said in comment, you can create a separated method which returns a Task for downloading photo data. And then you can download photos in parallel.

For more about this, you may refer to the official tutorial: [How to extend the async walkthrough by using Task.WhenAll (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/how-to-extend-the-async-walkthrough-by-using-task-whenall)